# Show list of opening tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is missing list of opening tab like this image:

[image]

Do anyone know how to show it again? Now my AS just show like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you see menu with count of the  open tab which is hidden on the right side your red mark. Click on that will list all the opening tabs which is not listing

Comment: No, you didn't got what I meant. I edited my question :)

Comment: Please click Project (left side) and open your java file from app-> java..

Comment: @Mrunal I solved this problem by the anwser below :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Window / Editor Tabs / tab placement ->top`  as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Window / Editor Tabs / Reopen Closed Tabs

Comment: In my Android Studio, the line "Reopen Closed Tabs" cannot click. (have a grey color).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is, goto: Window -> Editor Tabs -> tab placement ->top/bottom/left/right
If not work or any problem then, goto: Window -> Restore default layout. then try soluation.

And to know other Android studio User Interface name see there: [Click](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html#the_user_interface)